# How to achieve auto-pasting in Android

Tags: android, service, clipboard

I am an absolute beginner in android and I'm thinking about developing an app for automatically pasting clipboard content into the current textview.

Basic workflow should be like this:

1. Listen to clipboard change
2. When change detected

   - Get cursor position
   - Paste text into this position
3. Back to step 1

This looks quite simple but I need to find out what api functions/classes to use. Could anyone give some guidance in this?

Comment: From what the content would change in the first place ?

Comment: It could be any UI with a text field in it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a background thread that is always running with an infinite loop and a wait. Check there if the clipboard is different from the last one and report it to progress update (`publishProgress`). On onProgressUpdate update your UI with the text on the clipboard.

To paste the text and read the clipboard you can refer to this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html#Pasting